# Saving individual arrays from a loop in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

So I have an array x(i,j) which is inside a loop k = 1 to n, where n is set by the user. It updates every time I go to the next k. I was wondering if it's possible to save each of the arrays created in the loop to the memory so I can recall them at another time?

So for example, I was thinking I could do something along the lines of:

```
For k = 1 to n
...
SavedArray(k) = x(i,j)
...
next k
```

So I could recall, say for example, SavedArray(58) which would have been the 58th iteration of the loop.

Is this feasible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show your declaration of X ? , what is x(i,j) ? Do you want to save X , or just X(i,j) ?

Comment: X(i,j) is an nxn matrix of integers, If it helps I am solving a magic square problem in VBA. I would hyperlink you but I'm on my phone right now. If you google magic square then the Wikipedia link explains it sufficiently. All my code is set up for this but it is fairly lengthy to post here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you want to save the matrix each iteration? or just the integer in i,j '

Comment: I want to save the matrix each iteration. X(i,j) is actually a row and column reference. So if I have a 4x4 magic square, x(3,4) references the integer in the third row and 4th column.

Comment: So I want to save the matrix for all rows and columns, hopefully that makes sense

Comment: So you need to think about a way to save different size of matrices, and then just save it in another array.

Comment: Ok, so baring in mind the matrix stays the same size after the user has selected a dimension at the start of algorithm, would i need to save x(i,j) as an array with two dimensions as well, so MyArray(i,j)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is X, and what you wish to save.

If X(i,j) is just Integer so just make a new array and save it : `MyArr(k) = X(i,j)`

If X(i,j) is array (so X is 2D of 1D array ~ 3D) -you can use Array of Arrays to save it.

To simplify the solution you can create a new type, let say:

```
Public Type typeArray
    X(1 To 10)         As Integer 
    Y(1 To 10)         As Integer 
End Type
```

And Declare:

```
Public SavedArray(1 To 10)  As typeArray
```

Now you can use it as you wish.